# React Native FastImage not displayed in MapView.Marker children Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-native-fast-image

In my custom Marker i am displaying an image using react-native-fast-image, it displays it in predictable way on iOS, however doesnt on Android - just nothing